# Error in serializing data to a json file

Tags: c#, json

i have this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PushUpApp
{
    [DataContract]
    public class PushUps
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int TotalReps { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime Day { get; set; }
        public PushUps(int _totalReps,DateTime _day)
        {
            TotalReps = _totalReps;
            Day = _day;
        }
    }
}
```

and this methods:

```
public async Task writePushUpsAsync()
    {
        var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(PushUps));
        using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(FILE, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
        {
            jsonSerializer.WriteObject(stream, _pushUps);
        }
    }

private async void FinishButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PushUps _pushUp = new PushUps(reps, _day);
        if (_pushUps.Count!=0)
        {
            PushUps CurrentDayPushUp = _pushUps.Last();
            if (CurrentDayPushUp.Day.Day == _pushUp.Day.Day && CurrentDayPushUp.Day.Year == _pushUp.Day.Year && CurrentDayPushUp.Day.Month == _pushUp.Day.Month)
            {
                _pushUps.Last().TotalReps += _pushUp.TotalReps;
            }
            else
            {
                _pushUps.Add(_pushUp);
            }
        }
        else
            _pushUps.Add(_pushUp);
        await writePushUpsAsync();
    }
```

And i get this error

```
An exception of type
'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException'
occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Type
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[PushUpApp.PushUps,
PushUpApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'
with data contract name
'ArrayOfPushUps:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PushUpApp'
is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of
known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute
or by adding them to the list of known types passed to
DataContractSerializer.
```

What should i do?

Comment: Please show the type of `_pushUps`, most likely the serializer should be configured to `List<PushUps>` instead of `PushUps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing _pushUps is a list of some sort? Probably of type `List<PushUps>` or similar? (this is because I see `_pushUps.Add(_pushUp)`.

If that's the case, then you just need to update the `DataContractJsonSerializer` to use the list type, not the individual class. So change the line in `writePushUpsAsync` to something like this:

```
var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<PushUps>));
```

That's what the error means - it received an unexpected list instead of a single item.

Comment: Oh yees..Thank you!!